# Import data from a txt file via python

Tags: python, python-import

Can you please help me with the below code ? I can't understand why its not printing content of the txt file in a folder ?

```
import os
directory = raw_input( "Provide the folder location")
for files in os.listdir(directory): 
   if files.endswith(".txt"):
       f=open(files, 'r')
       for line in f.readlines():
          print line
```

Comment: Try to print `files`? Dies it exist? Does it end with `.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#os.listdir) only returns the names without the root folder.
In order to read the files, you have to deal with the full path:

```
fileFullPath = os.path.join(directory, files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the file since you try to open the filename and not the complete file path

you need to add the directory to your open method.

```
f=open(directory + files, 'r')
```

then it should work. 
you most likely got an FileNotFoundError error when you tried to run your code.

```
import os
dir = 'G:\Dev\\'
for files in os.listdir(dir):
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        f=open(dir + files, 'r')
        for line in f.readlines():
            print (line)
```

This code has hardcoded directory. raw_input has changed name to input in python3, you can modify your own code to make this work.